# Query using range of date in MongoDB in Java

Tags: java, mongodb, date

I am new at using MongoDB. I have it filled with receipts, for example: one receipt looks like this :

```
{ 
  "_id" : { 
          "$oid" : "510fa057c6f818c2bfd0b279"
          } ,

  "StoreName" : "Metro" ,
  "StoreNumber" : 521 , 
  "Items" : [ { 
               "ItemName" : "Battery" , 
               "ItemManufacturer" : "Duracell" ,
               "ItemPrice" : 12 ,
               "ItemQuantity" : 2 , 
               "ItemTotalPrice" : 24
              } , 

              { 
               "ItemName" : "TV CRT 25 inch" , 
               "ItemManufacturer" : "Toshiba" , 
               "ItemPrice" : 1659 , 
               "ItemQuantity" : 1 , 
               "ItemTotalPrice" : 1659
              } ,
              { 
                "ItemName" : "Mobile" , 
                "ItemManufacturer" : "Nokia" , 
                "ItemPrice" : 2966 , 
                "ItemQuantity" : 4 , 
                "ItemTotalPrice" : 11864
             }
          ] ,
  "Date" : {
            "$date" : "2012-06-16T01:21:11.758Z"
           } , 
  "Total" : 13547
}
```

I need to make a query where I specify a range of dates to get all the receipts in that range.  I've tried the following query, but it returns nothing.

```
  BasicDBObject query = 
       new BasicDBObject(
           "Date", 
           new BasicDBObject(
               "$gt", 
               "2012-06-20T10:05:21.968Z"
           ).append(
               "$lte",
               "2012-09-24T05:29:43.031Z"
           )
       );
```

Answer (score 6):

MongoDB dates work in conjunction with java.util.Date. Change your query to something like this :

```
Date start = new java.util.Date(2012, 06, 20, 10, 05);
Date end = new java.util.Date(2012, 06, 20, 10, 30);

BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject("Date", 
    new BasicDBObject("$gt", start)).
            append("$lte", end) ));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
    Date gtDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS").parse("2012-06-20T10:05:21.968");
    Date lteDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS").parse("2012-09-24T05:29:43.031");
    BasicDBObject dateQueryObj = new BasicDBObject("Date",  new BasicDBObject("$gt", gtDate).append("$lte", lteDate));

    DBCursor cursor = collection.find(dateQueryObj);
```